# Java loop with a replaceFirst Method

Tags: java

this is my first post on Stack Overflow, so please, be forgiving! :)

I have a list with 403 Polish registration plates symbols and counties. It looks like this:

BIA powiat białostocki

BBI powiat bielski

BGR powiat grajewski

CT Toruń
etc.

I made a code which let me to turn the first space into "=".

```
import java.io.*;
public class Test {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
     String Str = new String("BAU powiat augustowski");

     System.out.println(Str.replaceFirst(" ", "="));
}
}
```

How can I make a loop (for? do while?) to change all 403 records? I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have `List<String>` structure with all records?

Comment: Unfortunately I only have a list which looks like this:
/BAU powiat augustowski
/BIA powiat białostocki
/BBI powiat bielski.

I decided to use Java only because it has a replaceFirst method. I don't know this language at all.

Comment: So where is this list of strings coming from? A Database? A CSV text file? Do you want to print the modified strings or actually modify the source?

Comment: @TiiJ7 I would like to modify the source or print it and copy. Currently the list is in txt file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your list is a `List<String>`, you can do this :

```
for (for int i = 0, i < yourList.size(), i++) {
    yourList.set(i, yourList.get(i).replaceFirst(" ", "="));
}
```

Other ways to loop are available here : https://crunchify.com/how-to-iterate-through-java-list-4-way-to-iterate-through-loop/

Best

Comment: I think Jacek wants to change, not to print the elements of list

Comment: Edited my post.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to make a list and use your loop.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark the topic as answered :)

Answer (score 0):

You COULD also use Stream API. Eg if you want to filter all invalid strings

```
List<String> registrations = new ArrayList<>(5);
registrations.add("BIA powiat białostocki");
registrations.add("BBI powiat bielski");
registrations.add("BGR powiat grajewski");
registrations.add("BGGHND");
registrations.add("CT Toruń etc.");

registrations = registrations.stream()
                     .filter(registration -> registration.split(" ").length>1)  
                     .map(registration -> registration.replaceFirst(" ","="))
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Output:

```
    BIA=powiat białostocki
    BBI=powiat bielski
    BGR=powiat grajewski
    CT=Toruń etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned **how can make a loop** then I would suggest to learn java loop syntax at first. Following tutorial can be helpful

https://books.trinket.io/thinkjava2/chapter6.html

https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/6162/6-ways-to-iterate-or-loop-a-map-in-java

Regarding the solution, you can loop your lists using for/while loop or using Stream API. Here is your solution using stream API:

```
List<String> lists = new ArrayList<>();
lists.add("BAU powiat augustowski");
lists.add("BBI powiat bielski");

lists = lists.stream()
             .map(s -> s.replaceFirst("\\s", "="))
             .collect(toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Either if you are using an ArrayList or a HashSet you can use two ways:

Fyi: assuming your lists name is ***registrationList*** and it holds Objects names ***Registration***

Either a for loop:

```
for(Registration registration : registrationList){
    registration.replaceFirst(" ", "=");
}
```

Or you can use a Stream:

```
registrationList.stream.forEach(registration-> registration.replaceFirst(" ", "="));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have all lines in txt file and you want to modify that by replacing first space to `=` you could use stream API like:

```
List<String> collect = Files.lines(Paths.get(PATH_TO_FILE)).stream()
        .map(s -> s.replaceFirst(" ", "="))
        .collect(toList());

Files.write(PATH_TO_FILE, collect, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
```

See more [`StandardOpenOption`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html)